# Data on page is different than data in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, axios, momentjs

I'm performing a GET request to show information on a page---in my console I can see that the dates for `_data.Created` are correct, but on the page itself it's showing today's date of December 2nd. I'm using `moment.js` to format the Created date.

The most recent change I made was getting rid of a `<p>` tag that used to be in between the `<a>` tags, but I can't see how that would've messed with the dates. Also, I can't recall seeing this error in the past, but it's possible that I missed it.

Any ideas as to what's going on and how I can fix it? It would be much appreciated.

#### JS:

```
async function displayAnnouncements() {
    axios.get(`${_something}/_api/lists/GetByTitle('someName')/Items?$select=ID,Title,Body,Created,Link&$orderby=Created%20desc&$top=4`, restHeaders)
         .then(resp => {

            let _data = resp.data.d.results;
            let _newDate = moment(_data.Created).utc().format("MMMM D, YYYY");

            console.log(_data)

                _data.slice(0, 4).forEach(m => {
                    const itemLink = $(`<a href="#close" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bkEvts-${m.ID}" class="cont_evts-link" title="View Announcement">
                        <b>${m.Title}</b> - <i>${_newDate}</i>
                    </a><br>`)

// etc
```

Here's the console and the page:

[image]

Comment: `_data` is an array. So doing `moment(_data.Created)` will pass an invalid date and fall back to today.

Comment: [Here's what you need to know.](https://code-maven.com/logging-javascript-objects) Yeah, Objects in the console show the last state of the Object, so you might want to `console.log(JSON.stringify(_data));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_data` is an array. `_data.Created` will result in `undefined`. So you're passing `undefined` to `moment` which will fall back to today.

Instead format the date for each item in the array.

```
async function displayAnnouncements() {
    const resp = await axios.get(`${_something}/_api/lists/GetByTitle('someName')/Items?$select=ID,Title,Body,Created,Link&$orderby=Created%20desc&$top=4`, restHeaders)
    let _data = resp.data.d.results;
    _data.slice(0, 4).forEach(m => {
        let _newDate = moment(m.Created).utc().format("MMMM D, YYYY");
        const itemLink = $(
            `<a href="#close" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bkEvts-${m.ID}" class="cont_evts-link" title="View Announcement">
                <b>${m.Title}</b> - <i>${_newDate}</i>
            </a><br>`
        );
    });
};
```